# Why is this macro not getting expanded?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

This is the preprocessor output for `assets.cpp.i`:

```
#define CLASSNAME GAMEOBJECT
#define CLASSNAME_NORMAL GameObject
#define GAMEOBJECT_EXPANSION(FUNC) FUNC(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Component>>, comps)




# 1 "/home/rubend/p/engine/libs/include/prefab.h" 1

#define prefab_h 



#define PREFAB_VAR_ENUM_NAME(name) name ##_enum
#define PREFAB_VAR_ENUM_DIRTY(type,name) PREFAB_VAR_ENUM_NAME(name),


# 42 "/home/rubend/p/engine/libs/include/prefab.h"
#define _CLASSNAME_EXPANSION(classname,func) classname ## _EXPANSION(func)
#define CLASSNAME_EXPANSION(func) _CLASSNAME_EXPANSION(CLASSNAME,func)

template<class T>
class Prefab:public File{
private:
 std::shared_ptr<T> ref;

protected:

 enum DIRTY_ENUM{First, CLASSNAME_EXPANSION(PREFAB_VAR_ENUM_DIRTY) Last};

};
```

Now why is `CLASSNAME_EXPANSION(PREFAB_VAR_ENUM_DIRTY)` not expanding at all?

Is there something special about the concatenation token ## I don't know about?

I'm using GCC 9.3 and CMake 3.16.5

## **Answer**

Fixed it by adding another macro:

```
#define __CLASSNAME_EXPANSION(classname, func) classname ## _EXPANSION(func)
#define _CLASSNAME_EXPANSION(classname, func) __CLASSNAME_EXPANSION(classname,func)
#define CLASSNAME_EXPANSION(func) _CLASSNAME_EXPANSION(CLASSNAME,func)
```

### *Update* 12/4/20

@rici pointed out I should put the underscores in the end because internal library macros use them in the beginning.

Comment: To what should it expand?

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__CLASSNAME_EXPANSION`) and names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_CLASSNAME_EXPANSION`, `_EXPANSION`) are reserved for use by the implementation. Don’t use them in your code.

Comment: It should've expanded to `comps_enum,`

Comment: And thanks @PeteBecker, what would you recommend I use instead? Weighting the odds of such a long macro name conflicting with implementation vs the cleanliness of the underscore. I'd say the underscore wins

Comment: @ruben: put the underscores at the end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow the expansion, you will notice that CLASSNAME_EXPANSION is being expanded - to itself.

Let's take a look step by step at what happens:

```
CLASSNAME_EXPANSION(PREFAB_VAR_ENUM_DIRTY)
-> _CLASSNAME_EXPANSION(CLASSNAME,PREFAB_VAR_ENUM_DIRTY)
-> CLASSNAME ## _EXPANSION(PREFAB_VAR_ENUM_DIRTY)
-> CLASSNAME_EXPANSION(PREFAB_VAR_ENUM_DIRTY)
```

And since the name of this macro is the same as the original (i.e. it is a nested name) we do not expand it.

Comment: Just great... Thanks!